# How Do I Dot Source Functions Within a Subfolder in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, dot-source

I am attempting to create a PowerShell Module that will dot-source any functions found with the subfolder **"\Functions"** using the following code:

```
# Get the path to the function files
$functionPath = $PSScriptRoot + "\Functions\"

# Get a list of all the function filenames
$functionList = Get-ChildItem -Path $functionPath -Include *.ps1 -Name

# Loop through all discovered files and dot-source them into memory
ForEach ( $function in $functionList ) {
    . ( $functionPath + $function )
}
```

This is working fine if I drop all my functions directly inside the "\Functions" folder.  However, this is not ideal as I don't think it allows for proper management of the function files at the later time (*especially in a team environment where multiple SysAdmins could be modifying each function's script file at any given time*).  Additionally, some of the functions take input from CSV or Text files and it'll be much tidier to have those assets and the respective function contained within the same folder.

**Hence my question:**  How do I accomplish what I'm trying to do above (i.e., dot-sourcing ALL functions that are found within the **"\Functions"** subfolder of **$PSScriptRoot**, even if they are located within subfolders?

**PS.**  The end goal is to have a general purpose module that I distribute to all my admin workstations that will make available all the admin related scripts/functions we have created.  Then as we add and remove scripts they are dynamically updated in the module each time PowerShell is launched.

Credit goes to Bryan Cafferky in this [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgCRjWRliwE&t=2354s) for the inspiration

Comment: Why do you need the dot-sourcing?  if you want all of these functions to be available anyway, why not either just add them to the top-level module or their own modules and (assuming they are 'installed' correclty) they will be automatically available to the users in powerShell?

Comment: Because I don't want to manage multiple modules.  Also, if I place all the functions inside a single module, I would increase my risk of possible file corruption or create problems down the road if someone checks out the file and makes a mistake - the whole module would break.  This way, I isolate each function and the management thereof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify this a bit with a one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Functions\" -Filter *.ps1 -Recurse | %{. $_.FullName }
```

You were missing the `-Recurse` parameter and could have used `$function.FullName` rather than concatenating `$functionPath` and `$function`

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you, this worked like a charm.  Very much appreciated Rich.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.